# Querying after OSM Database created

Tags: postgresql, references, osmosis

I imported an OSM file into a Postgres DB using the Osmosis tool. Now, I need to extract some data but I can't find any schema description (I'm really a newbie in GIS).

Where can I find it?

Do you know if there is a tutorial to learn how to query an Osmosis Postgres DB?

I need to extract the names of all streets available within a given bounding box.

How can I do that?

Comment: what operating system are you running? http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/2/use-osmosis-postgis-schema-with-qgis

Comment: MacOS. I need to understand how the information are logically organized, for instance, given a town or administrative district, I need to extract all street under it

Comment: I'm pgsimple_schema_0.6 schema